# Android NestedScrollView scroll does not work

Tags: android, android-design-library

Title pretty much says it all. 
I have an Activity with a FrameLayout and I add a fragment at runtime. Data from the fragment are being displayed ok but I cant scroll.

The Activity's layout is :

```
    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/content_layout" 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbarLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/fl_content" android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" >

            <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        </FrameLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and the fragment's layout is :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView android:id="@+id/iv_cover"
    android:layout_width="100dp" android:layout_height="100dp" />

<TextView android:id="@+id/tv_release_artistname"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView android:id="@+id/tv_release_albumname"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView android:id="@+id/tv_release_year"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView android:id="@+id/tv_release_label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView android:id="@+id/tv_release_style"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView android:id="@+id/tv_release_notes"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make the `NestedScrollView` the parent of the `FrameLayout` and then add your `Fragment` on that `FrameLayout`.

Right now you're overwriting the contents of the `FrameLayout`, your `NestedScrollView` when you add your `Fragment` on top of it.

Also don't forget to add the `behaviour` on the `NestedScrollView` after switching.